# Poll different remote directories using SftpInboundAdapter and RemoteDirectoryExpression

Tags: spring-integration, spring-integration-dsl, spring-integration-sftp

I have an application that uses spring integration to poll files from the SFTP and process them. The structure of the sftp will be always similar, but new folders are going to be created. Example:

```
/sales/client1/in
/sales/client2/in
...
/sales/clientN/in
```

I'm using a Sftp Inbound Adapter to poll the SFTP server and start the flow, something like:

```
@Bean
public IntegrationFlow flow() {
    return IntegrationFlows.from(
            Sftp.inboundAdapter(sftpSessionFactory())
                    .preserveTimestamp(true)
                    .localDirectory(new File("sftp-inbound"))
                    .deleteRemoteFiles(true)
                    .autoCreateLocalDirectory(true)
                    .remoteDirectoryExpression(
                            EXPRESSION_PARSER.parseExpression("@directoryProvider.getDirectory()"))
                    .filter(getFilter())
            , e -> e.id("sftpInboundAdapter")
                    .autoStartup(true)
                    .poller(Pollers.fixedDelay(5, TimeUnit.SECONDS)))
            .log()
            .channel("processing")
            .get();
}
```

The bean `directoryProvider` will get the folders from the DB and will go in round-robin returning each folder, which according to what I understood from the documentation:

> Starting with version 4.2, you can specify remote-directory-expression instead of remote-directory, letting you dynamically determine the directory on each poll — for example, remote-directory-expression="@myBean.determineRemoteDir()"

it's what I'm needing, however, the method `getDirectory` is only executed twice when the IntegrationFlow is created and instead of getting a new folder on each poll, it uses the second one that was retrieved and is not asking again.

Did I understood wrong the documentation? Is there an easy way to do this, like a wild card for the intermediate folder structure? `sales/*/in` ? Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See [Inbound Channel Adapters: Polling Multiple Servers and Directories](https://docs.spring.io/spring-integration/docs/current/reference/html/sftp.html#sftp-rotating-server-advice).

Use a `RotatingServerAdvice` with a custom `RotationPolicy`.

Or use an outbound gateway instead, with a recursive MGET command.

https://docs.spring.io/spring-integration/docs/current/reference/html/sftp.html#sftp-outbound-gateway

Comment: Thanks, Gary, I really appreciate the time you took to answer me. Which one do you consider a better option? To create a custom `RotationPolicy` that retrieves the folders from the DB with an internal ExecutorService that polls the DB to keep that list updated or to use the MGET command and validate against the DB if the folder is valid?

Comment: The gateway is probably simpler and probably less code too - you can use a custom `FileListFilter` to filter the results of the recursive LS used to list the remote directory tree within the MGET logic.

Comment: One last question, for what the `remoteDirectoryExpression` is used then? I'm not following what the documentation means then when it refers to dynamically determine the directory on each poll

Comment: Looks like it was broken somewhere along the line - please open a GitHub issue referencing this question so we can investigate why; if it was intentional, we should at least fix the docs. It worked when I originally implemented it in 2015: https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-integration/commit/c68c7b3412cf2a10ffdc3e28136692be0408d112 - code here: https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-integration/blob/c68c7b3412cf2a10ffdc3e28136692be0408d112/spring-integration-file/src/main/java/org/springframework/integration/file/remote/synchronizer/AbstractInboundFileSynchronizer.java#L227-L228